# Enable cursorline only in preview window?

Tags: cursorline, previewwindow

How can I enable 'cursorline' in the preview window?

I use `:ptag` to show the preview and like that it shows several lines, but for short functions or member lists it's hard to see the line containing my tag. Using cursorline would help.

I tried this:

```
autocmd WinEnter * if &previewwindow | setlocal cursorline | endif
```

The preview window opens without a cursorline (even after `C-L` or `:redraw`), but when I switch to it cursorline activates. I want it to work without moving the cursor.

I tried WinNew instead of WinEnter, but that doesn't work at all. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:h BufWinEnter` is the event:

```
:autocmd! BufWinEnter * if &previewwindow | setlocal cursorline | endif
```

I guess the discrepancy is because WinEnter is triggered before 'previewwindow' is set. Possibly what's meant by this note in the help:

```
        Note: For split and tabpage commands the
        WinEnter event is triggered after the split
        or tab command but before the file is loaded.
```

Thanks to @romainl for the solution!

Comment: +1 for `BufWinEnter` and for the explanation of why `WinEnter` didn't work initially. That being said, [sometimes](https://imgur.com/a/2K2oCDp), the event is not fired when a preview window is opened. So, fwiw, I prefer [WinLeave](https://github.com/lacygoill/vim-window/blob/master/plugin/window.vim#L10).